# rails s 起動しません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rails s` を実行しようとすると以下のエラーが表示されて困っています。

調べたところ、すでにサーバーが起動しているとのことだったのでkillコマンドを用いて停止させるためのプロセスコマンドを調べられるpsコマンドを入力したところ以下が実行されましたがどれを入力すればいいか分かりません。
何方か教えていただけますと幸いです。

`ps` コマンドの実行結果

```
22912 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
22913 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
31805 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

`rails s` 実行時のエラーメッセージ

```
voclabs:~/environment/bookers (master) $ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.5.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        82: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        81: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        80: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
        79: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
        78: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        77: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/bin/spring:10:in `require'
        76: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        75: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        74: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        73: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        72: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        71: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:30:in `call'
        70: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:30:in `load'
        69: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
        68: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        67: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        66: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        65: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        64: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        63: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        62: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        61: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        60: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        59: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
        58: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
        57: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
        56: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
        55: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        54: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        53: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        52: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        51: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        50: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        49: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        48: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        47: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        46: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        45: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
        44: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        43: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        42: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        41: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        40: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        39: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        38: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        37: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        36: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        35: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        34: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        33: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        32: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        31: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:195:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        30: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
        29: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.5.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
        28: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:35:in `block in updater'
        27: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:21:in `reload!'
        26: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `load_paths'
        25: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `each'
        24: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.1.5.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `block in load_paths'
        23: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
        22: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
        21: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
        20: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `draw'
        19: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:427:in `eval_block'
        18: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:427:in `instance_exec'
        17: from /home/ec2-user/environment/bookers/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
        16: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:718:in `get'
        15: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:765:in `map_method'
        14: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1663:in `match'
        13: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1915:in `map_match'
        12: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1915:in `each'
        11: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1921:in `block in map_match'
        10: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1957:in `decomposed_match'
         9: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1985:in `add_route'
```

Answer (score 1):

> 調べたところ、すでにサーバーが起動している

railsが起動済みの場合、複数起動すると以下のように表示されます。
already runningのメッセージを確認してください。

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.2.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
A server is already running. Check /Users/owner/Documents/ruby/app/app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

railsの起動を確認するときはpsの出力結果からgrepでpumaを拾えばいいです。

```
$ ps ax | grep puma
8624 s000  S+     0:00.67 puma 5.6.4 (tcp://localhost:3000) [app]  
8732 s001  S+     0:00.00 grep -i puma
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。おっしゃられたpsの出力結果からgrepでpumaを拾った結果、10779 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto pumaと出力されたのでkillコマンドで10779と入力して強制終了させようとしたらbash: kill: (10779) - No such processと出力され、調べるとそのようなプロセスはないとのことでした。何が間違えているのか教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: ＞10779 pts/1 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto puma

これはあなたが実行したgrepプロセスが表示されているだけです。
ruby(puma)のプロセスではありません。
psでこの1行しか表示されないということは、railsは元から起動していません。